# Improve efficiency of distance matrix calculation for time series with dtw in big dataset with python

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing, hierarchical-clustering, dtw

I'm trying to improve the distance matrix calculation of all possible paris in a dataset of 109489 elements.

All the elements on the column are time series (stored as lists) and the metric I'm using to do the calculations is DTW.

I've created the following code that's working kind of good but I want to improve it because it will take almost a year to finish the calculations:

```
import numpy as np
import joblib
import _ucrdtw

def compute_distance(cycle1, cycle2):
    return _ucrdtw.ucrdtw(cycle1, cycle2, 0.05, False)

cycles = joblib.load('new_cycles.pkl')

dim_matrix = np.empty((len(cycles),len(cycles)), dtype=object)
with joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=15, verbose=10) as parallel:
    for i in range(len(cycles)):
        print(i)
        dim_matrix[i] = parallel(joblib.delayed(compute_distance)(
            cycles.iloc[i]['cycle_info_scaled'], 
            cycles.iloc[j]['cycle_info_scaled']) for j in range(len(cycles)))
```

This is an example of what's stored in the column `cycle_info_scaled` of the data frame:

```
cycle_info_scaled
[0.9948399033268663, 0.9948399033268663, 0.995...   
[1.0005639107922013, 1.00041937494038, 1.00020...   
[0.9975316557982873, 0.9975316557982873, 0.997...   
[1.0004695161595962, 1.000252692084482, 1.0002...   
[0.9919345197891065, 0.9919345197891065, 0.991...   
...
[0.9888568683957731,...
[1.0588396740044068,...
[0.9830848045072209,...
[0.9918426003000614, 0.9918426003000614, 0.991...
```

The purpose if to use this code to do a clustering of the time series
I'm kind of amateur in coding and Machine learning...
How can I improve the efficiency of this code?

Comment: While the time can be drastically improved, this clearly looks like a *XY problem*. The resulting matrix is *HUGE* and I do not see any reason to create such a matrix entirely. Indeed, it will take `109489**2*8 = 89.3 GiB` of RAM. Because Numpy often creates many temporary array, you will end up by needing a machine with at least 256 GiB of RAM which not reasonable. (btw note that manually looping on pandas dataframe cells is known to be slow and such questions as been already asked previously several times).

Comment: Hi Jerome, thanks for your comment.
I'm new in the machine learning world and I need to cluster the time series in the column, what would you suggest to cluster the presented data?

Comment: I am not very familiar with machine learning but AFAIK the best clustering method is dependent of the dataset. One of the most famous one is K-means and you do not need a huge matrix to run it, mainly just the distance function. If it is slow, you can use Cython or Numba or even write it in C/C++ if this is not enough (operating on large dataset often require efficient method and native languages or to use library doing that for you). KDtrees/Balltrees may help you too (they also need the distance function). AFAIK there are many other methods but very few require the full matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I've being checking on the different methods and, as the time series I want to cluster are different in length, I've found that hierarchical clustering could be a good approach but it requires a proper distance calculation between the time series to help me to weight them.