# Conditional broadcasting assignment of numpy matrix with array of index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy matrix filled with some values (I'm using zeros and just two topples to make the example easy to present the example with the two conditions):

```
nparray = array([[0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., (2, 2.5), 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., (1, 6.5), 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I have a sub matrix that is the result of some calculations that needs to be assigned in some specific index location in **nparray**:

```
sub_array= array([[(1, 3.2) ,  (2, 3.2),  (3, 4.6), (4, 3.4)],
                  [(3, 4.5) ,  (4, 0.4),  (5, 3.2), (6, 2.3)],
                  [(3, 4.5) ,  (5, 2.3),  (7, 5.3), (9, 2.3)],
                  [(12, 3.2), (45, 2.4), (32, 2.3), (6, 5.4)]], dtype=object)
index = [1, 2, 5, 9]
```

I need to assign the values in **sub_array** to **nparray** in the position of the result of **index** values combinations only if the value in **nparray** is not a tupple or if the value of the second item of the tupple in **sub_array** is lowest that the second value of the tupple in **nparray** at the same position , resulting in something like (I'm adding the index at the top to make the assignment location clear):

```
--------Index-----  0 | 1       | 2        | 3 | 4 | 5        | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9        

nparray =   array([[0., 0.      , 0.       , 0., 0., 0.       , 0., 0., 0., 0.      ],
     |       1     [0., (2, 2.5), (2, 3.2) , 0., 0., (3, 4.6) , 0., 0., 0., (4, 3.4)],
     |       2     [0., (3, 4.5), (4, 0.4) , 0., 0., (5, 3.2) , 0., 0., 0., (6, 2.3)],
     i       3     [0., 0.      , 0.       , 0., 0., 0.       , 0., 0., 0., 0.      ],
     n       4     [0., 0.      , 0.       , 0., 0., 0.       , 0., 0., 0., 0.      ],
     d       5     [0., (3, 4.5), (5, 2.3) , 0., 0., (7, 5.3) , 0., 0., 0., (9, 2.3)],
     e       6     [0., 0.      , 0.       , 0., 0., 0.       , 0., 0., 0., 0.      ],
     x       7     [0., 0.      , 0.       , 0., 0., 0.       , 0., 0., 0., 0.      ],
     |       8     [0., 0.      , 0.       , 0., 0., 0.       , 0., 0., 0., 0.      ],
     |       9     [0.,(12, 3.2), (45, 2.4), 0., 0., (32, 2.3), 0., 0., 0., (6, 5.4)]])
```

As you can see the **sub_array** is assigned in the locations of all the **index** array combinations.

For the tupple in position (1,1) the value is not replaced because the second item value in **nparray** (2.5) is lowest than the second item value in **sub_array** (3.2), in the other hand the tupple in position (2,1) is replaced because the second item value in **nparray** (6.5) is highest than the second item value in **sub_array** (4.5)

How can I achieve this conditional assignment with NumPy to ensure also time efficiency and not to go through a loop?

**Pd**:
My main objetive is to calculate a distance matrix based on some prior filtering, my dataset has 110K and it will take half a year to complete the calculations If I run it trough the entire set and not for a subset of it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic indexed assignment:

```
In [60]: index = np.array([1,2,6,7]); data = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
In [62]: res = np.zeros((10,10),int)
```

We can select a (4,4) block of values:

```
In [63]: res[index[:,None],index]
Out[63]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

and assign the (4,4) `data` to it as well:

```
In [64]: res[index[:,None],index] = data

In [65]: res
Out[65]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  2,  3,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  4,  5,  0,  0,  0,  6,  7,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  8,  9,  0,  0,  0, 10, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 12, 13,  0,  0,  0, 14, 15,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

What exactly is your `sub_array`?  If I just copy-n-paste, I get a (4,4,2) array:

```
In [67]: sub_array= np.array([[(1, 3.2) ,  (2, 3.2),  (3, 4.6), (4, 3.4)],
    ...:                   [(3, 4.5) ,  (4, 0.4),  (5, 3.2), (6, 2.3)],
    ...:                   [(3, 4.5) ,  (5, 2.3),  (7, 5.3), (9, 2.3)],
    ...:                   [(12, 3.2), (45, 2.4), (32, 2.3), (6, 5.4)]], dtype=object)

In [68]: sub_array.shape
Out[68]: (4, 4, 2)
```

I can't assign that to `res`

I can make a (4,4) array with tuple elements via:

```
In [69]: sub_array= np.empty((4,4),object) 
    ...: sub_array[:] = [[(1, 3.2) ,  (2, 3.2),  (3, 4.6), (4, 3.4)],
    ...:                   [(3, 4.5) ,  (4, 0.4),  (5, 3.2), (6, 2.3)],
    ...:                   [(3, 4.5) ,  (5, 2.3),  (7, 5.3), (9, 2.3)],
    ...:                   [(12, 3.2), (45, 2.4), (32, 2.3), (6, 5.4)]]

In [70]: sub_array
Out[70]: 
array([[(1, 3.2), (2, 3.2), (3, 4.6), (4, 3.4)],
       [(3, 4.5), (4, 0.4), (5, 3.2), (6, 2.3)],
       [(3, 4.5), (5, 2.3), (7, 5.3), (9, 2.3)],
       [(12, 3.2), (45, 2.4), (32, 2.3), (6, 5.4)]], dtype=object)
```

And assign the values to another object dtype array:

```
In [71]: res = np.zeros((10,10),object)
In [73]: res[index[:,None],index] = sub_array

In [74]: res
Out[74]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, (1, 3.2), (2, 3.2), 0, 0, 0, (3, 4.6), (4, 3.4), 0, 0],
       [0, (3, 4.5), (4, 0.4), 0, 0, 0, (5, 3.2), (6, 2.3), 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, (3, 4.5), (5, 2.3), 0, 0, 0, (7, 5.3), (9, 2.3), 0, 0],
       [0, (12, 3.2), (45, 2.4), 0, 0, 0, (32, 2.3), (6, 5.4), 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

In fact I could start with the nested list of tuples, and skip `sub_array`:

```
In [75]: res = np.empty((10,10),object)

In [76]: alist = [[(1, 3.2) ,  (2, 3.2),  (3, 4.6), (4, 3.4)],
    ...:                   [(3, 4.5) ,  (4, 0.4),  (5, 3.2), (6, 2.3)],
    ...:                   [(3, 4.5) ,  (5, 2.3),  (7, 5.3), (9, 2.3)],
    ...:                   [(12, 3.2), (45, 2.4), (32, 2.3), (6, 5.4)]]

In [77]: res[index[:,None],index] = alist

In [78]: res
Out[78]: 
array([[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, (1, 3.2), (2, 3.2), None, None, None, (3, 4.6), (4, 3.4),
        None, None],
       [None, (3, 4.5), (4, 0.4), None, None, None, (5, 3.2), (6, 2.3),
        None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, (3, 4.5), (5, 2.3), None, None, None, (7, 5.3), (9, 2.3),
        None, None],
       [None, (12, 3.2), (45, 2.4), None, None, None, (32, 2.3),
        (6, 5.4), None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]],
      dtype=object)
```

Another option is to start with a (10,10,2) numeric `res`, and copy the (4,4,2) `data` to it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. As you stated, sub_array is an 4x4 matrix with tupples objects. I’m sorry if the code is not returning this. I like your answer, then I guess I need to add the conditioning part! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: just noticed your additional constraint on which tuple to take in the case there is already a tuple at the given index. I'm headed out the door but perhaps this is enough for OP to go from here.

I believe this gets you what you want, via some pretty straightforward indexing:

```py
In [34]: arr = np.array([[0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...:                  [0., (2, 2.5), 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...:                  [0., (1, 6.5), 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...:                  [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...:                  [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...:                  [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...:                  [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...:                  [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...:                  [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...:                  [0., 0.      , 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=object)

In [35]: arr
Out[35]:
array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, (2, 2.5), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, (1, 6.5), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=object)

In [36]: idx = np.ix_([1, 2, 5, 9], [1, 2, 5, 9])

In [37]: sub = np.asarray([[(1, 3.2) ,  (2, 3.2),  (3, 4.6), (4, 3.4)],
    ...:                   [(3, 4.5) ,  (4, 0.4),  (5, 3.2), (6, 2.3)],
    ...:                   [(3, 4.5) ,  (5, 2.3),  (7, 5.3), (9, 2.3)],
    ...:                   [(12, 3.2), (45, 2.4), (32, 2.3), (6, 5.4)]], 'float,float')

In [38]: arr[idx] = np.where(arr[idx], arr[idx], sub)

In [39]: arr
Out[39]:
array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, (2, 2.5), (2.0, 3.2), 0.0, 0.0, (3.0, 4.6), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        (4.0, 3.4)],
       [0.0, (1, 6.5), (4.0, 0.4), 0.0, 0.0, (5.0, 3.2), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        (6.0, 2.3)],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, (3.0, 4.5), (5.0, 2.3), 0.0, 0.0, (7.0, 5.3), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        (9.0, 2.3)],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, (12.0, 3.2), (45.0, 2.4), 0.0, 0.0, (32.0, 2.3), 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, (6.0, 5.4)]], dtype=object)
```

However, I've gotta ask -- *why?!* Why are you storing your data like this? This completely defeats the purpose of numpy...

Comment: Hi,I'm just saving the result of a calculations that happens to be a tupple.

Comment: But why use a numpy array? What calculations are these? You *could* store your results in a 3D array, where the first axis separates the first and second elements of each tuple (i.e., the first axis has only two elements, each of them a 2D array where the first array is all the "x" coordinates of these tuples and the second array is all the "y" coordinates). That would make it much easier to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: All this come because I’m trying to calculate a distance matrix for a dataset of 110K elements as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72610242/improve-efficiency-of-distance-matrix-calculation-for-time-series-with-dtw-in-bi?noredirect=1#comment128286895_72610242. I’m broadcasting the computations, that’s the reason of having a numpy array